# Stack Allocation For Functions

Tags: c++, memory, stack, overflow, allocation

Is there any quantative testing for functions in modules/source files regarding memory allocation as seen in the following 32 bit build:

```
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
wchar_t TestArray [516332]  = { NULL };
}
```

It succeeds for 516332 (or 7E0EC) but produces a stack overflow for 516333.
Of course, a global decl of 2Gb or 7FFFFFFF is legal, but add one to get the SO.

```
#include <windows.h>
wchar_t TestArray [2147483647]  = { NULL };
int main()
{
}
```

Using VS10/MCBS in a 32 bit build, but the X64 doesn't play nice. Is there a proportional increase for function types (e.g. long, char void, bool) in 64 or 128 systems? Specifically searching for answers with a numerical/tableau approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I get your question right, but:

```
int main()
{
    wchar_t TestArray [516332]  = { NULL };
}
```

Here you are hitting the limit of the default 1MB thread stack size (some other data will already be on the stack too). The default size can be adjusted using `/STACK:reserve[,commit]` in Visual Studio.

```
wchar_t TestArray [2147483647]  = { NULL };
int main()
{
}
```

Here you are hitting the 2GB user mode limit on a 32 bit system (which can be altered using the /3GB startup switch).

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know about the `/STACK:reserve[,commit]`. Would that be the same regardless of the *type* of function (modified question a little)?

Comment: @LaurieStearn - The stack is measured in bytes, so it depends on what type of data you put on it. I'm not sure what you mean with funtion types, but the parameters are also pushed on the stack (unless they are stored in registers directly) - together with local variables (which can also be arrays). For seperate threads, started from the main thread, a paramter can be given for the stack size.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is "no". There is no way to "check" how much stack-space there is available, or how large the stack is. Some runtime systems has the knowledge of the stack space, but there is no standard for that, and technically, the C++ standard (or the C standard) does not even dictate that there should be a stack as such (although it would be rather difficult to build a system without SOME kind of stack, but technically it wouldn't have to be a hardware register for stack pointer, and argument passing could be done via some other mechanism altogether).

It is technically possible to have a larger stack in a 64-bit system - I don't think anyone has started thinking about real 128-bit systems yet - we've got a fair way until current systems use up the available bits in 64-bit - current memory mapping only copes with 53 bits - to get more, changes would be required in the page-table handling. And current processors tend to have 48 bits of memory address actually implemented - that still gives 65536 * 4GB, or 256TB. With current systems having 1-2TB as maximum, we have a fair bit to go before we'll run out of what is currently available.

Although technically possible to be much bigger, even in a 32-bit environment, the stack size is typically limited to a few megabytes. For large volumes of data, you want to use the heap, which is much less limited - and if you do run out, it's possible to recover, which is typically not the case from running out of stack-space [and using large amounts of stack in a function is typically bad, because other "consumers" of that function may not realize how much memory it uses]. For small variables, up to a few hundred bytes, the overhead of allocating from the heap will be noticeable, but for very large objects, like a few hundred thousand `wchar_t`, the overhead of allocating it on the heap is marginal, so that would be the "right" thing to do.

For something string-like, I would suggest:

```
std::wstring TestString(size);
```

Assuming you have a desired size - it will allow you to allocate a single string at that size, and the max size is limited by the combination of available memory and the max allocation size (which is system dependent, but should be at least 2GB or thereabouts).

Comment: Interesting. So the value of 7E0EC can vary on different installations? "Cheated" a bit by adding a little more to the question. It's probably something I can do myself: Would the value of 7E0EC vary according to function *type*?

Comment: The calls preceeding "your" function will matter - so if you have a function that uses, say `int arr[1000];`, then your `0x7E0EC` will be smaller by approximately `0x1000`. I'm not sure what a *type* of function is - yes,  different return-type from a function  - a `struct { int a[500]; } func(...)` will use more than `int func(...)` The "installation" isn't what matters, but the C and C++ runtime, compiler and OS will all affect the actual and default (and often max) size of the stack. In other words, Windows will be different from Linux, but two similar variants of Linux will be the same.

Comment: If this based on some kind of formula, is it possible to locate documentation for it?

Comment: There is no strict formula. For a given platform, the default stack size is X. For a given function F1..Fn the stack usage is Y1..Yn. Sum of all Y1..Yn active in the current call is how much stack you use. The goal should ALWAYS be to not run out of stack.